# Dompdf No carga imágenes ni css Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy generando un pdf utilizando Dompdf con Codeigniter, sin embargo no me están cargando los estilos ni las imágenes dentro de la plantilla html desde la que lo estoy generando ¿Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

De acuerdo a la documentación debería de utilizar

```
 <img src="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT' ]./assets/materiales_informes/logo.png ?> ">
```

Sin embargo esto genera un error, asumo que es por las comillas simples, si le agrego comillas dobles, no genera ningún error pero tampoco se muestra la imagen

```
$html ='<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Porcentaje de Citas</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/materiales_informes/style.css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
<header class="clearfix">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/materiales_informes/logo.png">

  </div>
  <h1>INVOICE 3-2-1</h1>
  <div id="company" class="clearfix">
    <div>Company Name</div>
    <div>455 Foggy Heights,<br /> AZ 85004, US</div>
    <div>(602) 519-0450</div>
    <div><a href="mailto:company@example.com">company@example.com</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="project">
    <div><span>PROJECT</span> Website development</div>
    <div><span>CLIENT</span> John Doe</div>
    <div><span>ADDRESS</span> 796 Silver Harbour, TX 79273, US</div>
    <div><span>EMAIL</span> <a href="mailto:john@example.com">john@example.com</a></div>
    <div><span>DATE</span> August 17, 2015</div>
    <div><span>DUE DATE</span> September 17, 2015</div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="service">SERVICE</th>
        <th class="desc">DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th>PRICE</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="service">Design</td>
        <td class="desc">Creating a recognizable design solution based on the companys existing visual identity</td>
        <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
        <td class="qty">26</td>
        <td class="total">$1,040.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="service">Development</td>
        <td class="desc">Developing a Content Management System-based Website</td>
        <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
        <td class="qty">80</td>
        <td class="total">$3,200.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="service">SEO</td>
        <td class="desc">Optimize the site for search engines (SEO)</td>
        <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
        <td class="qty">20</td>
        <td class="total">$800.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="service">Training</td>
        <td class="desc">Initial training sessions for staff responsible for uploading web content</td>
        <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
        <td class="qty">4</td>
        <td class="total">$160.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">SUBTOTAL</td>
        <td class="total">$5,200.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">TAX 25%</td>
        <td class="total">$1,300.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="grand total">GRAND TOTAL</td>
        <td class="grand total">$6,500.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="notices">
    <div>NOTICE:</div>
    <div class="notice">A finance charge of 1.5% will be made on unpaid balances after 30 days.</div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  Invoice was created on a computer and is valid without the signature and seal.
</footer>
</body>
</html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilzar esto

```
href="<?php echo base_url('application/assets/materiales_informes/logo.png')?>"
```

https://brunosweb.blogspot.mx/